# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>

Tags: javascript, arrays, casting, htmlelements

This is the line that gives me the error:

```
var modalList = document.getElementsByClassName("modal") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
```

This was based off a HowTo tutorial found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp), but my page will have multiple modal images so I changed a few things. I found many examples of casting the return value of `.getElementsByClassName` to `HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>`, which is necessary in my case since I will be accessing some of the properties later. If most other examples work, why won't this one? My script tag is at the bottom of the body.

Comment: I think the `as` keyword is in Typescript, not native Javascript